# Managing Multiple Windows w/ Properties

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm building an application with multiple forms each with their own public properties. I create multiple instances of them and hide the form when the user closes it just to maintain it's property values in memory. I don't want to move the properties somewhere more consistent because there are so many different forms, accessed often and I'm trying to stay organized. I also don't want to hide all the potential unused forms just to store these property values. What's the best way to handle a situation like this?

I hope you can understand what I mean without showing any code. I would be happy to if you think it will help, but I'm trying to be general here. I think it's more of a methodology question.

Comment: You've already ruled out moving them somewhere. Do you know about `#Region`?  A more OO approach is to use classes to store, manage, verify, save and load the data related to an Actor (Customer, Player, Game, Order, Product etc).  Forms then, are just the way those things get or show information to the user and the question would be irrelevant

Comment: I think I understand what you mean. I'm still trying to wrap my head around it. Say I have frmOne with no public properties, it's stores nothing, just an interface. I can create a class called dataOne or something with all it's public properties, call them when frmOne is created, write them back on save and let frmOne dispose on close. Is it that simple?

Comment: `dataOne` and `frmOne` are a bit too abstract. Think of a simple game of BlackJack.  You might (should) have a card class that indicates the `{Rank, Suit, Value, Image}` for a card.  Its simple.  A Deck class would have the tasks of creating a collection of 52 of them, shuffling to make a shoe, collecting the muck, and dealing cards.   A Game class might specify certain params (Easy level  = 1 deck shoe, Med = 3 deck shoe etc); It might also control whether it is 5 card draw, 7 card stud or Texas Hold Em.  Now, how would a form have a role in any of that?

Comment: Those were just vague examples. I just need to picture forms more like empty hollow shells and move the properties out of them and into their own class it sounds like. I believe I know what I need to do now. Thanks.

Comment: Actually rather than starting with a form or visual, start with the functionality; what does the app do, what classes does that functionality imply etc.  *Then* build the forms to implement the desired functionality.  Starting with forms and visuals you are sort of building from the outside in - that inherently results in bottlenecks and roadblocks.  Building from the inside out, form follows function.

Answer (score 0):

One of the good ways to do it is to use Memento pattern. for example, in pseudo-code:

Lets say you have a form with properties. Form is of course memory-heavy and you want to have your properties "remembered" but not the form

```
' declare memento interface
Interface IForm1Memento
    ' declare properties here
    . . . . . 
    Sub SetMemento()
    Sub GetMemento()
 End interface    

 ' inherit in form
 public class form form1
     inherits IForm1Memento
     . . . . 
     Sub SetMemento
          dim m As IForm1Memento = MementoFactory.Get(me)
          ' here you can do property by property or create reflection based hydrator
          ' or use AutoMapper (free product) to fill memento object (see below)
          MementoStorage.Store(key, m) ' this could be a global dictionary or cache like nCache
     end sub

     Sub GetMemento
          dim m As IForm1Memento = MementoStorage.Retrieve(key)
          ' again, here hydrate your form from memento
     end sub

 end class


 ' inherit interface in memento object
 public class Form1Memento
     inherits IForm1Memento
     ' here ho same property implementations as in form1
 end class
```

Now, if you also decorate your `Form1Memento` with xml attributes, you could store it in file system and retrieve it on next app startup. Or, you can use JSON if you like.

so, what do we have as result? - form can go, close and load. as a matter of fact, you can load memento on `form.load` and save on `form.closed`. You can persist your memento on file system or store in memory - in cache, in dictionary, in list, etc.